# Java Applet Printing dialog won't go away

Tags: java, security, printing, applet, next-generation-plugin

I have a simple java applet that retrieves an image from a server and prints it out.  The only problem is that I get the following java security warning:

[image: error message]

Researching on this site and all over the web, some people suggest that I sign the applet (I tried that to no avail) and others suggest that I [Modify a local java security setting](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1534660) but that isn't feasible for my clients.

Not only do I get this warning at the start of my applet, but seemingly any time the code attempts to interact with the printer, the dialog re-appears.  Also, note that there is no checkbox next to 'Always allow this applet to access the printer'.  These symptoms show on any browser.

How do I get java to respect the users choice to allow it to send jobs to the printer?

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I confirmed that the applet is signed and signed correctly.  I'm not very familiar with jnlp but I do not believe it will fit with my needs because I need this to happen within a webpage, not with a user clicking on something to start an external tool.

Comment: Andrew!  Thanks for your help!  using JNLP was indeed the solution to the problem.  Feel free to put your response as an 'answer' below and I'll choose it as the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use the JNLP API services in a sand-boxed applet in a plug-in 2 JRE. They will still prompt the user each first time they go to print, but should also put an 'always allow' check-box on the dialog (though it really only applies for that run). See a [demo. of the `PrintService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#prs).

See also the [applet info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) that includes a link on the Next Generation in Applet Java Plug-in Technology which "..brings new abilities to applets: such as .. allowing embedded applets to gain full access to the services of Java Web Start."