# Preventing applet security warning for printing

Tags: java, security, printing, applet

I have an application that pops up with the message:

```
Security warning
The applet has requested access to the printer
Do you want to allow this action?
```

If I add this line: 
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "queuePrintJob";`

Manually to file:

```
C:\program files\Java\jre.1.5.0\lib\security
```

No more message displays..

How can I solve this? Like signed applet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Applet Printing dialog won't go away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708523/java-applet-printing-dialog-wont-go-away)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I solve this? Like signed applet?

Yes.  Digitally sign the code and then convince the user to OK it when prompted at (before) load, and the applet should be able to do further secure actions (print, access personal information, trash the user's disks or install the slave-bot..) unprompted.

I personally, would prefer to be prompted for printing explicitly, as and when the applet goes to print when invoked by my specific command (which would be never).  But maybe it is just me.

Comment: I'm not a Java Programmer. So, I dont know how can I sign my java applet. How can I do this? Should I pay some money? (like buying SSL certificate)

Comment: Yes, get a proper digital certificate if you can.  There are lots of different types so be careful which you get. You might be surprised at the price.  The alternative for the common developer is to use a self signed certificate.  But that does not provide the security to the user, of the certificate from a Certification Authority.

Comment: I'm using this java applet only 20-30 client. This isn't public application. Since now, I used it with manualy edit java policy file. But, it's problem on java upgrade. Because, I need to edit policy file manualy on every client when java is updated :(